# Rolling mean for Rle objects in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to efficiently calculate rolling mean for an object of `Rle` class, without having to convert it to a numeric vector first?

For example:

```
rl <- Rle(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2))
```

I want to get:

```
zoo::rollmean(as.integer(rl), k=3)
```

but this approach doesn't work for large vectors.
Any other ideas?

Comment: What length does you large vector have that doesn't work?

Comment: package RcppRoll might help

Comment: I am working with integer-Rle of length about 10e8, with about hundred runs, so the memory is limiting factor, I can't even load it in R as a regular vector